# Empty map on flutter when initiating

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Map user = {};

  Future<void> getUser(String idProfile) async {
    final response = await ac.getItem("/v2/users/:0", [idProfile]);
    if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
      setState(() {
        user = json.decode(response.body);
        print(user);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUser(getCurrentUser());
    print(user);
  }
```

With the first print, it returns me the user. However, at the second doesn't. I need to get the user information. How could I do it?

Comment: `getUser` is a future method, you need to wait until it fetches data from API.

Comment: How can I make a function that returns a future as a String?

Comment: It won't be needed while `user` is empty initially,

Comment: On my controller, the function is:
  String getCurrentUser() {
    return _USER_ID;
  }

Comment: If something depends on future, you need wait to fetch it, You can check [async-await colab](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)  and also on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getUser` is a future method, you need to wait until it fetches data from API. While you are using `StatefulWidget` , you can show landing indication while it fetch data from API.

If it is inside  `Column` widget,

```dart
  if (user.isEmpty) Text("fetching data") 
  else LoadDataWidget(),
```

Also you can use ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Map user = {};

//Return a user from the function
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUser(String idProfile) async {
    final response = await ac.getItem("/v2/users/:0", [idProfile]);
    if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
        user = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        return user
  
    }
    else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
// Set the user value in initstate 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = getUser(getCurrentUser());
    print(user);
  }
```

Comment: I have problems because it returns a Map<String, dynamic> but my map is <dynamic, dynamic> and when i try to change it it gives me multiple errors

Comment: If possible can you share the data here as it is being returned . It'd help to look at how the data is structured